# How to stop shake gesture in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using shake gesture for creating new post in my app. How to stop shake gesture during Onboarding screen?

```
override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEventSubtype,
                              with event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .motionShake {
        if self.revealtype == "opened" {
            self.revealViewController().revealToggle(self)
        } 

        datearray.removeAll()

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        let monthdate = dateFormatter.string(from: NSDate() as Date)

        datearray.append(monthdate)
        selectnsdate  = Date()
        print("success")

        let ivc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "selectpost") as? SelectPost
        ivc?.shake = true
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(ivc!, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add shake gesture on viewWillAppear and remove gesture on viewDidDisappear viewController’s methods. So when you push another view controller shake gesture will not trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by simply swallowing motionShake events by implementing the following in your onboarding view controller:

```
override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEventSubtype,
                         withEvent: UIEvent?) {
    if motion != .motionShake {
        super.motionEnded(motion, withEvent: withEvent)
    }
}
```

(The documentation for `motionEnded` states that "the default implementation of this method forwards the message up the responder chain".)